# Content Deployment Error: The Remote Upload Web Request Failed

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am having issues with a content deployment.  It was working fine on Friday morning.  When we tried to run a deployment on Friday evening the content deployment failed with an error of "The remote upload web request failed".

I've been Googling things for a while, it's not an issue with a file size or destination server name error.

The Event that's being thrown is:

Id: 4958
Description: Publishing Content deployment job failed.  Error: 'System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)...

I have done some tests with other deployments from this authoring server:

When I tried to deploy this site to a new site collection (in the same web application) on the destination farm, it failed (same error).

When I tried to deploy a new site collection (from the same web collection on the authoring farm) to a new site collection (in the same web application) on the destination server it deployed just fine.

I have limited the site "Specific sites within the site collection" down to just the root site for deployment.  This still fails.  There are no files large enough to exceed the cab size.

Can anybody point me in the direction of some other things to look for?  I haven't found much info on this Content Deployment error, when it is throwing a 500 error in the Event Viewer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)' seems to indicate that you're facing some sort of an internal (web) server error. At least HTTP error code 500 get's me that idea.

Is the rest of the web server functioanllity of that particular server working correctly?

HTH

Comment: Yep, I'm able to access and work with the authoring site and sites on the destination server work just fine.  I was even able to do a deploy of a new site collection in the source web application to a new site collection in the destination web application.  

On the deployment logs.  The export completes but 0 objects are imported before the deployment fails.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a red herring, but have you tried restarting the Indexing service on the server you are deploying too ?

I had deployment issues in Sharepoint a while back, where this resolved it.

[Link here...](http://oldnick.typepad.com/msblog/2009/01/access-is-denied.html)